# Can we use windsor castle IOC container in DD4T CD application?

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t, 2013-sp1

We have few applications which are developed using DD4T 1.31 and uses Ninject IOC container.
Currently we need to integrate another application which uses Windsor Castle IOC container with DD4T Application.
In this case should i change the DD4T application Ninject IOC container to Windsor Castle IOC container?
If so can you please suggest what are the changes we need to do?

Can you please suggest which container is best for DD4T applications?

Thanks,
Prasanna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windsor Castle officially is not a supported IOC container with DD4T, however, I can confirm it would work with minor changes with DD4T 1.31 as well as DD4T 2.0 - you need to follow the Castle documentation for all necessary changes.

You may also need to register all required classes (different for DD4T 1.31 and DD4T 2.0) with Castle.Windsor.

There are couple of cautions while using Castle with DD4T 2.0 and might require you to briefly override the Page Factory class

Comment: Hi Pankaj, Thanks for the information This answered my question. One more doubt when compared Ninject by using Windsor Castle will it have  any performance gain the reason is I am seeing in blogs saying Ninject is slow in performance. Thanks,

Comment: Castle Windsor is quite good, that's what all I can say